# Transparent Content in Webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, opacity, transparent

My task is to show HTML content with half-transparent elements in WPF app. Transparency should go through Webbrowser and window. Webbrowser should not be half-transparent itself.
So i need a HTML content, and i need to see desktop through it.

Is there any way to do something like that?

Thank you.

P.S.: Sorry for my English.

Comment: Take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changov/archive/2009/01/19/webbrowser-control-on-transparent-wpf-window.aspx

Comment: @Jack - link not working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Awesomium](https://www.awesomium.com/)** and **[Awesomium.NET](https://www.awesomium.com/)** is an HTML UI Engine that supports just that.

Check the WPF [`WebControl`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=T_Awesomium_Windows_Controls_WebControl). You can set [`WebControl.IsTransparent`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=P_Awesomium_Windows_Controls_WebControl_IsTransparent) to `true`, and load some content with say `body { background-color: transparent; }` (you can even specify a custom CSS to be applied to all loaded pages, using [`WebSession`](http://wiki.awesomium.net/general-use/using-web-sessions.html)).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible; this is due to the way that the Web Browser control is rendered.  It isn't really a true WPF control but a WPF wrapper around a COM component.  This limits the functionality available and also causes other problems, such as the lack of ability to float WPF controls over the top of it.

I believe there is a new WebView control coming for Windows 8.1 apps (demoed at Build 2013). This may provide more flexibility, although I'm not sure if this is a Windows 8.1 app thing or whether it will also be available to WPF apps as part of .NET 4.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

The WPF Web Browser control is technically a wrapped WinForms WebBrowser Control, so it is rendered in the WinForms layer, which is always above the WPF layer.you can use [Awesomium.NET](http://awesomium.com/) Browser instead IE Browser or convert your [Html code to Xmal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gduthie/archive/2009/11/03/wpf-sample-convert-html-to-xaml-and-back.aspx) code and show in [Flow Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx) control.[WPF Flow Document For Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37368/WPF-Flow-Document-For-Beginners)